# How can I access the properties of an image?

Tags: import, image, properties

I have imported an image, and using `FullForm` I can see that the image has a collection of properties, e.g. `Rule[Interleaving, None]`. What I can't work out is how to access any of those properties. Clearly, I am missing something very simple.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am using this problem as a general example of how to access the properties of any object. I know that I could use e.g. ImageDimensions etc., but I want to understand how to access any property, whether it has a getter function defined, or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules you mention can be extracted using [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html). Note that this does not find all properties, e.g. the image dimensions are not explicitly stored in the `Image`.

#### Example:

```
In[1]:= Options@ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]
Out[1]= {ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True, 
 MetaInformation -> <|"Comments" -> <|"Software" -> 
      "Wolfram Mathematica 8.0", 
     "Creation Time" -> 
      DateObject[{2010, 2, 18, 12, 43, 31.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 
       2.]|>|>}
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you so much. I find Mathematica's language quite confusing - as a newbie. I was searching for properties, and attributes, and even entity values. I would not have thought of 'options'.

Comment: "…this does not find all properties, e.g. the image dimensions are not explicitly stored in the `Image`." - I would imagine that the properties not stored are as such because they can be easily derived from the result of `ImageData[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Some information is stored in options:

```
Import["path/to/file.png", "Options"]
```

> `{"BitDepth" -> 8, "ColorSpace" -> RGBColor, "ImageSize" -> {419, 348}}`

More information is available by using "Rules":

```
Import["path/to/file.png", "Rules"]
```

This is only for use with images stored on your computer. It is not for images that have already been loaded into *Mathematica*. (To get data from already imported images, use Mathe 172's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see what is inside any of the Mathematica data structures using FullForm. For example, for the image:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
FullForm[img]
```

is a long list. It starts with

```
Image[RawArray["UnsignedInteger8", ....
```

followed by a long list of Lists (which are the pixel values in the image array). It ends with

```
 "Byte", Rule[ColorSpace, "RGB"], 
 Rule[Interleaving, True], Rule[MetaInformation, 
 Association[Rule["Comments", 
 Association[Rule["Software", "Wolfram Mathematica 8.0"], 
 Rule["Creation Time", 
 DateObject[List[2010, 2, 18, 12, 43, 31.], "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.]]]]]]
```

which gives more information about what is inside an Image. Similarly, you can look inside sound objects and other data structures.